# Merging several large datasets - Memory issue

Tags: r, merge

I have about 15 different Data sets in R that I need to merge into 1 big Data set.

Combining them will create a data set of about 1120 variables and about 1500 observations.

There is no problem merging the first 5 data sets (getting to about 700 variables), but when trying to merge the 6th/7th dataset R either get stuck or have an error msg of:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.7 Mb

I have tried different ways to write this code (functions/loops), but this is the simplest way, by which I understood that it gets stuck on the 6th dataset:

```
#Merging the first two data sets
#bindedDataNames is a chr vector with the names of all the datasets that need            
#to be merged. 
Age11_twins_22022017 <- merge(eval(parse(text = bindedDataNames[1]))
                          [,-c(1:2)],
                          eval(parse(text = bindedDataNames[2]))
                          [,-c(1:3)],
                          by=c("ifam","ID"))

#Loop to merge all datasets. With print I saw it goes without a problem until         
#the 6th dataset
for (cnt2 in 3:17) {
  print(cnt2)
  Age11_twins_22022017 <- merge(Age11_twins_22022017,
                            eval(parse(text = bindedDataNames[cnt2]))
                            [,-c(1:3)],
                            by=c("ifam","ID"))
}
```

I saw that there are packages for big data such as `bigmemory` or `ff`, but couldn't really figure out how to write the merge result (which is different from step to step) into this big matrix.

Is it even possible in R to merge several datasets into a really big one?

I would want to both be able to export this file to later use in SPSS and be able to do statistical analysis in R itself.

Comment: This is by no means a large dataset. Either you are working on a computer with very little memory available to R, or your code is very inefficient/bugged. Please share your code first.

Comment: I have tried to do run this code on 2 different computers, and it didn't work on either. I have now added to the previous post the simplest version of code I tried to do. Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you need the `eval(parse(text=))`? And are you sure you only get around 1500 observations with the merge? How many rows are there already before it fails? Or do you mean to `cbind` instead of `merge`?

Comment: I have 18 different objects in R, each is a data frame. To access them in a loop, I have a chr vector with their names, and the `eval(parse(text=))` takes the names from the chr vector and translate it into an object. Can it help if instead I'll make a list from all the objects and access them through the list? 
I mean to do `merge` (and not `cbind`) because each data frame has different info on participants, and it is important to merge by an identifier.